# List most recently modified files in a `ls`-style output without running `ls` on the entire directory?

Tags: files, ls, date

I have a directory with tens of thousands of files. I want to list the most recently modified files (for example files modified within the last day or whatever).

The following command works but is slow because it has to `ls` every file in the folder:

```
ls -rt | tail -n 10
```

The following command is faster but the output is not as detailed as `ls`:

```
find -mtime -1
```

Is there a way I can list the most recently modified files (either a set number or by date) with `ls`-like output but faster?

Comment: I removed the `bash` tag, as I didn't see anything bash-specific in your question. Different shells have different capabilities, so if bash is a hard requirement, please make that clear in the body of the question (along with the tag). Otherwise, [tag:shell] would be appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

At least the GNU and FreeBSD `find`s have the `-ls` action, which produces output similar to `ls`:

```
$ find . -ls
   392815      4 drwxr-xr-x   2 user  group      4096 Jul 22 18:39 .
   392816      0 -rw-r--r--   1 user  group         0 Jul 22 18:39 ./foo.txt
   392818      0 -rw-r--r--   1 user  group         0 Jul 22 18:39 ./bar.txt
```

GNU find also has very configurable output in the form of the `-printf` action.

That said, I do wonder what makes your `ls` so slow. Both `find` and `ls` need to read the whole directory and call `lstat()` on all the files to find the dates, so there shouldn't be much of a difference. `ls` does need to sort the whole list of files, so that could make a difference if there is a really large number of files. In that case, you might want to consider spreading the files out to different directories, possibly based on their date. Dropping the `-r` and use `head` instead of `tail` might help.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the zsh shell available, it can do some of the date filtering and sorting for you:

#### list the two most recent files:

```
ls -ld -- *(om[1,2])
```

(add the `D` glob qualifier to also consider hidden files).

#### list the two oldest files (counting backwards from the end of the generated list):

```
ls -ld -- *(om[-2,-1])
```

Or:

```
ls -ld -- *(Om[1,2])
```

#### list the files that were modified more than 5 days ago:

```
ls -ld -- *(m+4)
```

(like for `find -mtime +4` that's when the age rounded down to a number of days is *strictly* greater than 4).

#### list the files that were modified within the past 5 days:

```
ls -ld -- *(m-5)
```

These are all examples of ["Glob Qualifiers"](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn). The zsh shell is doing all the hard work here; it comes up with the matching filenames (if any) and passes that list to `ls` for it to list out.

Note that if you want to limit the results to only plain files (not directories, sockets, pipes, etc), then use a `.`; for example:

#### list the *plain* files that were modified within the past 5 days:

```
ls -ld -- *(.m-5)
```

Comment: You may want to add `.` in the list of qualifiers, to be sure to only get regular files, e.g. `*(.Om[1,2])`

Comment: I had started to sprinkle them in, but then I thought "directories are files, too", and 
Stéphane edited them out.  The question doesn't specify regular files in the prose or the examples, but it's a good qualifier to know about, regardless!

Comment: ... and you're using `ls` with `-d` anyway. Fair enough.